# Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:80 in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

when i execute the program with npm start, appears:

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:896:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:919:20)
    at cb (net.js:1311:16)
    at rr (cluster.js:620:14)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:590:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:750:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:718:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:444:11)
CLUSTER: Worker 177 disconnected from the cluster.
CLUSTER: Worker 177 died with exit code 1 (null)
CLUSTER: Worker 181 started
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

if change the port from 80 to 8080, the program executes, but don't conect to api.localhost:3000

Comment: **info** : You must be `root` to get the system ports *(< 1024)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a privileged user, you should be able to list processes referring to TCP port 80 using:

```
netstat -plant | grep LISTENING | grep :80
```

On the right column, you should find a process name and corresponding PID, that would indicate who's listening on that port.

Using a debian or el7 based system, nowadays, you would usually need to install the `net-tools` package, providing with the `netstat` command.

As suggested by Gregory NEUT, maybe you do not have enough privileges binding on :80. Although AFAIR, in those case, you should get an `EACCESS` error. Whereas `EADDRESSINUSE` would indicate an other application is already listening on `TCP:80`. It might even be a previous copy of your application, running in background.

Answer (score 6):

`EADDRINUSE` means "**E**rror **ADD**ress already **IN USE**"

So you probably have another process listening on the port 80

On linux, you can list ports in use with the command `netstat -a | grep LISTENING | grep 80`